# Using a custom DataAbortHandler in WindowsCE

Tags: arm, windows-ce

We're developing an application based on Windows CE. At the moment we're fighting with numerous data abort exceptions that only occur with release builds. We only have a limited number of development devices, that actually output their debug stream onto the serial port. Now we're wondering if it is possible to use OemDataAbortHandler to access the content of the Exception (i.e. everything that is written to the debug stream) in order to gather the data for diagnostic purposes. 
Ideally we'd be able to create a textfile containing data like this:

```
    Exception 'Data Abort' (4): Thread-Id=05a70002(pth=8252169c),
 Proc-Id=03cf000e(pprc=824f3d70) 'XXXX.exe', VM-active=03cf000e(pprc=824f3d70) 'XXXX.exe'
    PC=400323cc(coredll.dll+0x000223cc) RA=4003361c(coredll.dll+0x0002361c) SP=0102f27c, 
BVA=6464646c
```

Now, the signature of OemDataAbortHandler is:

```
void OEMDataAbortHandler(void);
```

Is there any way to get access to the data written to the debug stream?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Structured Exception Handling (`__try`/`__except`) to filter the data abort exception. The processor state at the time of the exception is returned in the `CONTEXT` argument of the `GetExceptionInformation` intrinsic function. See the [documentation for try/except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s58ftw19%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).